# Пустое значение в поле внешнего ключа

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Вот такой вопрос знатокам:
Пользователь вводит данные о машине, отсылает на сервер, если по введенным данным можно определить марку машины (ее id_car в таблице cars) то в ссылающуюся таблицу (user_cars) заносим просто id_car марки, если id_car марки машины определить нельзя - то заносим все введенные данные в таблицу user_cars. Так вот в таблице user_cars нельзя создать ключ id_car и сослаться по нему на таблицу cars, но так, чтобы при желании поле было пустым. Или можно? Если нельзя, то как решить задачу? Надеюсь, вопрос сформулировал более-менее понятно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам просто нужно сделать связь с таблицей cars. А в таблице `user_cars` полю `id_car` нужно указать свойство Null.

Т.е. Вам нужно выполнить такой запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_cars` CHANGE `id_car` `id_car` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Только одно замечание: поле `id_car` должно быть проиндексировано, но не быть первичным индексом (в таблице `user_cars`). А то я щас пытался сделать как написал. Пока не убрал первичный индекс, свойство NULL поле (колонка таблицы) принимать не хотело. Ну это в принципе и понятно почему.

Comment: Кхм... Получилось. Что я сделал: 
Проиндексировал поле id_car в таблице user_cars (в этой таблице первичный ключ - id_user_cars (один ползователь может иметь несколько машин)), затем создал внешний ключ из user_cars по полю id_car (которое может быть NULL)в cars на поле id_car, которое тут - первичный ключ...

Честно говоря, я не понимаю, что значит, что в таблице user_cars я проиндексировал поле id_car (при чем указал, что это поле не уникальное (один польователь может иметь две машины одной марки))... Можете пояснить, пожалуйста?)

Comment: @Nikoole, я не понял Вас. Вы проиндексировали поле `id_car`. Да, в этой таблице это поле и должно быть не уникальным. Проиндексировали вы это поле затем, чтобы потом иметь возможность сделать связь. Но перед этим вы должны выполнить запрос, который я написал выше. Что конкретно вам непонятно?

Comment: Не понятно что дает эта индексация... Ну просто интересно зачем она нужна. Что происходит когда я проиндексировал поле.

Comment: Индекс делает выборку данных более быстрой. Индексация - построение индекса, в поисковых системах все сайты индексируются (там составляется обратный индекс - слова встречающиеся на сайте запоминаются: их количество, позиция в тексте и т.д.), а здесь используется прямой индекс. Т.е. mysql уже заранее будет знать где искать `id_car` с таким значением (например, 5 или 557), а не перерывать весь файл в поиске этого значения.